# app.yaml vs appengine-web.xml which one to use?

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, spring-boot, yaml

I am using Google App Engine flexible to deploy my spring boot app. I see the configuration can be specified by app.yaml or appengine-web.xml. However, my questions are,

1. Which configuration file should I use for the Spring boot app, yaml or xml?
2. If xml, should I create web/WEB-INF/ folder and place the appengine-web.xml under that?
3. Also, if xml how to specify the "flex" environment choice (via which property) in the xml?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my oppinion, I think you should use xml file as static configuration with less changing because xml syntax is complex. And use yaml file for application properties which sequense changing. Yaml format is human readable.

Comment: I think the yaml configuration is ignored if the xml configuration is present?

Comment: I doubt that - none of the 2 config files completely covers **all** parameters covered by the other one. They're rather complementing each-other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use both files.

The [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) file covers configurations applicable to all flexible environment apps/services, regardless of the language they're written in, like:

- the `flex` environment and other [General settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#general)
- [Network settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#network_settings)
- [Health checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks)
- [Service scaling settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#services)

The [`web.xml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor) config file has a very specific coverage, which doesn't overlap the `app.yaml` file's coverage:

> The `web.xml` file is only used when deploying a Java app to a runtime
>   that includes the Jetty9/servlet3 server. For more details, see [the
>   Java 8 / Jetty 9.3 Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-jetty9).

As for your #2 question, you may have been looking at the standard env docs (check the `docs/standard` or `docs/flexible` strings in the doc's URL). From [`web.xml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor):

> This file is named `web.xml`, and resides in the app's WAR under the
>   `WEB-INF/` directory. `web.xml` is part of the servlet standard for
>   web applications.

Comment: Sure. Yes, I am aware of the web.xml in the web apps. My question was focusing on appengine-web.xml which holds the specific configuration for app engines.

Comment: I was referring to this xml and properties and please note few overlapping properties  *https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref?hl=en#Java_appengine_web_xml_System_properties_and_environment_variables*. So you mean that appengine-web.xml is only for app engine standard environment and flexible only uses app.yaml?

Comment: Yep - standard env only.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or/45842773#45842773

Comment: I think the two files are equal in power. By the way, you can specify <env>flex</env> param in appengine-web.xml. Something messy, isn't it? :)

Comment: i ran the command "mvn appengine:run" got this exception : Failed to run devappserver: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/tiago_sllater/Spring-Boot-GCP/target/Catalog-Service-0.0.1/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml

Comment: I have no idea why this answer is accepted when it is both wrong and missing the point of the question.